# What are the return values of system calls in Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, return-value, nasm, system-calls

When I try to research about return values of system calls of the kernel, I find tables that describe them and what do I need to put in the different registers to let them work. However, I don't find any documentation where it states **what** is that return value I get from the system call. I'm just finding in different places that what I receive will be in the EAX register.

---

[TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_system_calls.htm):

> The result is usually returned in the EAX register.

*Assembly Language Step-By-Step: Programming with Linux* book by Jeff Duntemann states many times in his programs:

> - *Look at sys_read's return value in EAX*
> - *Copy sys_read return value for safe keeping*

---

Any of the websites I have don't explain about this return value. Is there any Internet source? Or can someone explain me about this values?

Comment: Try googling "sys_read".  Here is something I found. http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html

Comment: @MarkLakata I tried but didn't help. As I stated, it only says what do I need to put in different registers so the syscalls work. (e.g. [here](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html) and [here](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64).)

Comment: If you google "sys_read" the 4th link is this: https://lwn.net/Articles/604287/ and it has all the gory details.

Comment: @MarkLakata: Thanks for the link; added to my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See also [this excellent LWN article about system calls](https://lwn.net/Articles/604287/) which assumes C knowledge.

Also: [The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls (on x86)](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/), and related: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)

---

C is the language of Unix systems programming, so all the documentation is in terms of C.  And then there's documentation for the minor differences between the C interface and the asm on any given platform, usually in the Notes section of man pages.

`sys_read` means the raw system call (as opposed to the libc wrapper function).  The kernel implementation of the `read` system call is a kernel function called `sys_read()`.  You can't call it with a `call` instruction, because it's in the kernel, not a library.  But people still talk about "calling `sys_read`" to distinguish it from the libc function call.  However, it's ok to say `read` even when you mean the raw system call (especially when the libc wrapper doesn't do anything special), like I do in this answer.

Also note that `syscall.h` defines constants like `SYS_read` with the actual system call number, or `asm/unistd.h` for the Linux `__NR_read` names for the same constants.  (The value you put in EAX before an `int 0x80` or `syscall` instruction).

---

Linux system call return values (in `EAX`/`RAX` on x86) are either "normal" success, or a [`-errno` code](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) for error.  e.g. `-EFAULT` if you pass an invalid pointer.  This behaviour is documented in the [`syscalls(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) man page.

**-1 to -4095 means error, anything else means success**.  See [AOSP non-obvious syscall() implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551940/aosp-non-obvious-syscall-implementation/47566663#47566663) for more details on this `-4095UL .. -1UL` range, which is portable across architectures on Linux, and applies to *every* system call.  (In the future, a different architecture could use a different value for MAX_ERRNO, but the value for existing arches like x86-64 is guaranteed to stay the same as part of Linus's don't-break-userspace policy of keeping kernel ABIs stable.)

For example, glibc's [generic `syscall(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) wrapper function uses this sequence:  `cmp rax, -4095` / `jae SYSCALL_ERROR_LABEL`, which is [guaranteed to be future-proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996410/linux-kernel-system-call-returns-1-instead-of-1-256/18998521#18998521) for all Linux system calls.

You can use that wrapper function to make any system call, like `syscall( __NR_mmap, ... )`.  (Or use an inline-asm wrapper header like https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/linux-syscall-support/blob/master/linux_syscall_support.h that has safe inline-asm for multiple ISAs, avoiding problems like missing `"memory"` clobbers that some other inline-asm wrappers have.)

---

Interesting cases include `getpriority` where the kernel ABI maps the -20..19 return-value range to 1..40, and libc decodes it.  More details in [a related answer about decoding syscall error return values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44820591/224132).

For mmap, if you wanted you could also detect error just by checking that the return value isn't page-aligned (e.g. any non-zero bits in the low 11, for a 4k page size), if that would be more efficient than checking `p > -4096ULL`.

---

To find the actual numeric values of constants for a specific platform, you need to find the C header file where they're `#define`d.  See [my answer on a question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38604334/224132) for details.  e.g. in `asm-generic/errno-base.h` / `asm-generic/errno.h`.

---

The meanings of return values for each sys call are documented in the section 2 man pages, like [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).  (`sys_read` is the raw system call that the glibc `read()` function is a very thin wrapper for.)  Most man pages have a whole section for the return value.  e.g.

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates
> end    of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  It
> is    not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
> requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are
> actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-
> file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or
> because read() was interrupted by a signal.  See also NOTES.
>
> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.  In this
> case, it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any)
> changes.

Note that the last paragraph describes how the glibc wrapper decodes the value and [sets errno](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno) to `-EAX` if the raw system call's return value is negative, so `errno=EFAULT` and return `-1` if the raw system call returned `-EFAULT`.

And there's a whole section listing all the possible error codes that `read()` is allowed to return, and what they mean specifically for `read()`.  (POSIX standardizes most of this behaviour.)

Comment: 1. Does *sys_read* equals `read()`? 2. What is `-errno`, `-EFAULT` and `-retval`? How is it related to Assembly?

Comment: @PichiWuana: 1. yes, of course.  2. C is the language of Unix systems programming.  Everything is documented in C terms.  C is basically just portable assembly language.  [`errno` is a global](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) which is set after any library function encounters an error. `-` is the C unary negation operator.  `EFAULT` is an integer constant defined by a C preprocessor macro.  `retval` is a variable name I made up to describe what EAX holds after a system call.

Comment: Does that mean that if you know good Assembly programming you will understand C easily? And vice versa?

Comment: @PichiWuana: Well, C is way too portable for its own good, so there are a lot of rules like signed overflow being undefined behaviour, and right shifts of signed types being implementation-defined whether they do an arithmetic or logical shift.  But yes, knowing asm is helpful in understanding how C works, and vice versa.  Pointers and arrays in C work the same as in asm.  Knowing both, I can easily see how simple C functions will compile to asm.  You can even use this knowledge to [hand-hold a compiler into making better asm by tweaking the source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34410357/224132)

Comment: @PichiWuana: Updated my answer a bit, to assume less C knowledge.  I just assumed that part was all obvious, since I knew Unix systems programming in C before I learned about how it actually works under the hood in asm.