# AOSP non-obvious syscall() implementation

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm, system-calls, libc

As far as I know Linux ABI for ARM states that syscall return value is passed via `r0` and if it is negative it should be threaded as errno value negated. I.e syscall has ended up with some error.
AOSP [does this check](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/arch-arm/bionic/syscall.S#47) in some fancy way:

```
ENTRY(syscall)
    mov     ip, sp
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7}
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_rel_offset r4, 0
    .cfi_rel_offset r5, 4
    .cfi_rel_offset r6, 8
    .cfi_rel_offset r7, 12
    mov     r7, r0
    mov     r0, r1
    mov     r1, r2
    mov     r2, r3
    ldmfd   ip, {r3, r4, r5, r6}
    swi     #0
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7}
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
    cmn     r0, #(MAX_ERRNO + 1) /* Set C flag if r0 is between -4095 and -1, set Z flag if r0 == -4096 */
    bxls    lr                   /* return if Z is set or C is clear */
    neg     r0, r0
    b       __set_errno_internal
END(syscall)
```

Looks like this function won't threat `r0 < -4096` as error condition. While it should. Of course real `errno` will fit into allowed gap, but anyway what was rationale to perform check in that way instead of just testing `r0` for negativity?

P.S. If I've missed something or just my analysis is incorrect - any comments appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the particular system call, other negative values might not be errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how Linux's system-call ABI/API is designed, only a limited range of `-errno` values are allowed, to avoid using up half the range of possible return values for a small set of error codes.  (Nobody will ever need more than 4095 errno codes?)

As @Timothy points out, `mmap` is a great example: it needs to return a pointer.  `mmap`'s return value is always page-aligned, so on systems with 4k pages or larger pages (i.e. almost(?) everything), `-4095` is the highest magnitude negative number you can use without also being a valid page address.

**`-4095` = `2^32 - 4095` in a 32-bit 2's complement system.  The highest page-start address is `2^32-4096`**.  This is the obvious motivation for picking exactly *this* range as the ones that mean "error".

(But note that you still can't mmap the highest page of virtual address space, [even for a 32-bit process under a 64-bit kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47712502), even though `-4096UL` would be a non-error return from `mmap`.  The kernel *internally* uses the same in-band `-errno` code mechanism for pointers, not just for the system-call ABI, so it reserves the top page to prevent ever having a valid pointer that's also an error code.  That also avoids the possibility of corner cases like a pointer to one-past-end of an array being 0 (NULL).)

---

The range of values which mean error is in theory platform-dependent and part of the syscall ABI, but AFAIK Linux uses `[-4095..-1]` on every platform it supports.  The MUSL libc implementation hard-codes `-4096UL` in a C source file that's not x86 or ARM-specific: [`/src/internal/syscall_ret.c`](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/internal/syscall_ret.c?h=v1.1.15).

As @Tsyvarev points out, **Linux defines `MAX_ERRNO` to 4095 [in `include/linux/err.h`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/err.h#L34), not an arch-specific header**.  (A comment points out that it could be made arch-specific if it ever needs to be, and that it was specifically chosen because of how kernel pointers work.)

The x86-64 System V ABI also has an informative (not normative) section on Linux system calls, where this `-4095` to `-1` range is specified.  ([Search for `-4095`](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)).  (Other platforms using x86-64 System V can vary their syscall ABI, like [FreeBSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66878250/freebsd-syscall-clobbering-more-registers-than-linux-inline-asm-different-behav/66881185#66881185) or MacOS)

---

Fun fact: this means `sys_getpriority` can't return the `nice` level directly.  Instead [it returns `20-nice`, which maps the `-20..19` range of nice values to `40..1`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sys.c#L252).  The libc wrapper function has to decode the nice value after the generic `retval > -4096UL` check detects a non-error return value.

---

Fun fact #2: the syscall ABI on some Linux platforms (e.g. MIPS and PowerPC) returns `-1` in the return value and the errno code in a separate register.  Source: comments in this [syscall inline-asm wrapper library](https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/linux-syscall-support/blob/455f05ae2c0ab1c7a4160c0e5addb7b99be6d793/linux_syscall_support.h#L1842).  (Looks like a good library; avoids problems like missing `"memory"` clobbers that some syscall wrapper headers have.)

---

Related:

- [What are the return values of system calls in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751614/what-are-the-return-values-of-system-calls-in-assembly)
- [Linux System Calls, Error Numbers, and In-Band Signaling](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/09/23/) (using x86-64 examples, but the concept is of course identical).  The key concept here is **In-Band Signaling**.
- [The Definitive Guide to Linux System Calls (on x86)](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/)

Answer (score 3):

Typically the return value of `mmap` is negative if interpreted as a signed number.

Answer (score 2):

Apper limit 4095 for errno value is intentional, and using this knowledge in the code is fine. Practically, this modifies model of value, returning by syscalls and some other kernel functions, to:

- `[-4095 ... -1]` - error
- other values - result

This model allows more possible values for result. E.g., if interpret result as unsigned long integer, then value's range for result is extended from `[0... (MAX/2)]` to `[0 ... (MAX - 4096)]`. This is useful, e.g. when result is a pointer, see [implementation](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/err.h#L34) of `IS_ERR` macro.