# Segmentation fault when replacing `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and `free` via `LD_PRELOAD`

Tags: c, linux, malloc, x86-64, ld-preload

#### Background

I am experimenting to replace `malloc(3)`/`calloc(3)`/`realloc(3)`/`free(3)` via `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable. I have tried to use the customized functions statically linked, they worked perfectly.

But, when I attached it as shared library to `LD_PRELOAD`, it always results in segfault.

---

#### Short technical explanation about functions

- I use Linux x86-64 `mmap(2)` and `munmap(2)` syscall for `malloc(3)` and `free(3)`.
- The `calloc(3)` is just a call to `malloc(3)` with multiply overflow check.
- The `realloc(3)` calls `malloc(3)`, then copy old data to new allocated memory and unmap the old memory.

---

#### Questions

- What is wrong with my approach so that it always result in segfault?
- How can I debug it (gdb and valgrind also segfault)?
- What did I miss here?

---

#### Note

I am fully aware that always using `mmap` for every `malloc` call is a bad idea, especially for performance. I just want to know why my approach doesn't work.

---

#### Output

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ gcc -shared mem.c -O3 -o my_mem.so
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/my_mem.so ls
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/my_mem.so cat
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/my_mem.so w
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/my_mem.so gdb ls
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/my_mem.so valgrind ls
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$
```

---

#### glibc version

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.33-0ubuntu2) release release version 2.33.
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 10.2.1 20210130.
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC ABSOLUTE
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bugs>.
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$
```

---

#### Code mem.c

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>


static inline void *my_mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags,
                            int fd, off_t offset)
{
    void *ret;
    register int _flags asm("r10") = flags;
    register int _fd asm("r8") = fd;
    register off_t _offset asm("r9") = offset;

    asm volatile(
        "syscall"
        : "=a"(ret)
        : "a"(9), "D"(addr), "S"(length), "d"(prot),
          "r"(_flags), "r"(_fd), "r"(_offset)
        : "memory", "r11", "rcx"
    );
    return ret;
}


static inline int my_munmap(void *addr, size_t length)
{
    int ret;

    asm volatile(
        "syscall"
        : "=a"(ret)
        : "a"(11), "D"(addr), "S"(length)
        : "memory", "r11", "rcx"
    );
    return ret;
}

#define unlikely(EXPR) __builtin_expect(EXPR, 0)

void * __attribute__((noinline)) malloc(size_t len)
{
    void *start_map;
    uintptr_t user_ptr, cmperr;
    size_t add_req = 0;

    add_req += sizeof(size_t);
    add_req += sizeof(uint8_t);
    add_req += 0x1full;

    start_map = my_mmap(NULL, add_req + len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    cmperr = 0xffffffffffffff00ull;
    if (unlikely(((uintptr_t)start_map & cmperr) == cmperr)) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Align 32-byte and take space to save the length and diff */
    user_ptr = ((uintptr_t)start_map + add_req) & ~0x1full;
    *(size_t  *)(user_ptr - 8) = len;
    *(uint8_t *)(user_ptr - 9) = (uint8_t)(user_ptr - (uintptr_t)start_map);

    return (void *)user_ptr;
}


void free(void *__user_ptr)
{
    size_t len;
    uint8_t diff;
    uintptr_t user_ptr = (uintptr_t)__user_ptr;

    len  = *(size_t  *)(user_ptr - 8);
    diff = *(uint8_t *)(user_ptr - 9);
    my_munmap((void *)(user_ptr - diff), len);
}


void *realloc(void *__user_ptr, size_t new_len)
{
    void *new_mem;
    size_t len;
    uint8_t diff;
    uintptr_t user_ptr = (uintptr_t)__user_ptr;

    len  = *(size_t  *)(user_ptr - 8);
    diff = *(uint8_t *)(user_ptr - 9);

    new_mem = malloc(new_len);
    if (unlikely(new_mem == NULL))
        return NULL;

    memcpy(new_mem, __user_ptr, (new_len < len) ? new_len : len);
    my_munmap((void *)(user_ptr - diff), len);
    return new_mem;
}


void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t len)
{
    size_t x = nmemb * len;
    if (unlikely(nmemb != 0 && x / nmemb != len)) {
        errno = EOVERFLOW;
        return NULL;
    }
    return malloc(x);
}

// #include <stdio.h>
// int main(void)
// {
//  char *test = malloc(1);

//  for (size_t i = 2; i <= (1024 * 1024); i++) {
//      test = realloc(test, i);
//      memset(test, 'q', i);
//  }

//  free(test);
// }
```

---

### Recompile with `-Wall -Wextra -ggdb3` and `strace` output

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ 
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3 -shared mem.c -O3 -o my_mem.so
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ strace -tf /usr/bin/env LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/my_mem.so ls
12:59:15 execve("/usr/bin/env", ["/usr/bin/env", "LD_PRELOAD=/home/ammarfaizi2/my_"..., "ls"], 0x7ffd2d6ee188 /* 34 vars */) = 0
12:59:15 brk(NULL)                      = 0x565552193000
12:59:15 arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7ffd13017120) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=74118, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 74118, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7facba2ba000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\206\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0 \0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48, 848) = 48
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\30\355\366\266\203\242\371v\214\300\356\234\306J\346\373"..., 68, 896) = 68
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1983576, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7facba2b8000
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 2012056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7facba0cc000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7facba0f2000, 1486848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7facba0f2000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7facba25d000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x191000) = 0x7facba25d000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7facba2a9000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1dc000) = 0x7facba2a9000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7facba2af000, 33688, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7facba2af000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7facba0ca000
12:59:15 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7facba2b95c0) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7facba2a9000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x565550cb5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7facba2ff000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 munmap(0x7facba2ba000, 74118)  = 0
12:59:15 brk(NULL)                      = 0x565552193000
12:59:15 brk(0x5655521b4000)            = 0x5655521b4000
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3041456, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 3041456, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7facb9de3000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 execve("/home/ammarfaizi2/.local/bin/ls", ["ls"], 0x565552194550 /* 35 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 execve("/usr/local/sbin/ls", ["ls"], 0x565552194550 /* 35 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 execve("/usr/local/bin/ls", ["ls"], 0x565552194550 /* 35 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 execve("/usr/sbin/ls", ["ls"], 0x565552194550 /* 35 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls"], 0x565552194550 /* 35 vars */) = 0
12:59:15 brk(NULL)                      = 0x557f8624b000
12:59:15 arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fff39dc1a30) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/ammarfaizi2/my_mem.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=58768, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7daa68000
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 16448, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7daa63000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa64000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fa7daa64000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa65000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fa7daa65000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa66000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fa7daa66000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=74118, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 74118, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7daa50000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 p\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=167352, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 178664, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7daa24000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa2a000, 106496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fa7daa2a000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa44000, 32768, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x20000) = 0x7fa7daa44000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa4c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x27000) = 0x7fa7daa4c000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa4e000, 6632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7daa4e000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\206\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0 \0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48, 848) = 48
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\30\355\366\266\203\242\371v\214\300\356\234\306J\346\373"..., 68, 896) = 68
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1983576, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 2012056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7da838000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da85e000, 1486848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7fa7da85e000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da9c9000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x191000) = 0x7fa7da9c9000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa15000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1dc000) = 0x7fa7daa15000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7daa1b000, 33688, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7daa1b000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=617160, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 619304, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7da7a0000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da7a2000, 438272, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fa7da7a2000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da80d000, 167936, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6d000) = 0x7fa7da80d000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da836000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x95000) = 0x7fa7da836000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22912, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 24848, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7da799000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da79b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fa7da79b000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da79d000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7fa7da79d000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da79e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7fa7da79e000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\200\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0 \0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48, 792) = 48
12:59:15 pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0a7\363\352;k|\2228\244\6\253\346\2569\312"..., 68, 840) = 68
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=150456, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 136208, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa7da777000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da77e000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7000) = 0x7fa7da77e000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da78e000, 20480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7fa7da78e000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da793000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b000) = 0x7fa7da793000
12:59:15 mmap(0x7fa7da795000, 13328, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7da795000
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7da775000
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7da772000
12:59:15 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fa7da772800) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7fa7daa15000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7fa7da793000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7fa7da79e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7fa7da836000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7fa7daa4c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7fa7daa66000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x557f842f9000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 mprotect(0x7fa7daa9c000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
12:59:15 munmap(0x7fa7daa50000, 74118)  = 0
12:59:15 set_tid_address(0x7fa7da772ad0) = 1639769
12:59:15 set_robust_list(0x7fa7da772ae0, 24) = 0
12:59:15 rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7fa7da77eb70, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fa7da78b160}, NULL, 8) = 0
12:59:15 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7fa7da77ec10, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7fa7da78b160}, NULL, 8) = 0
12:59:15 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
12:59:15 prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
12:59:15 statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7fff39dc1a00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 statfs("/selinux", 0x7fff39dc1a00) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 512, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7daa9b000
12:59:15 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 160, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7daa62000
12:59:15 newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
12:59:15 mmap(NULL, 1064, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa7daa61000
12:59:15 read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\ttmpfs\nnodev\tbd"..., 1024) = 410
12:59:15 read(3, "", 1024)              = 0
12:59:15 munmap(0x7fa7daa62000, 120)    = 0
12:59:15 close(3)                       = 0
12:59:15 munmap(0x7fa7daa61000, 1024)   = 0
12:59:15 munmap(0x7fa7daa9b000, 472)    = 0
12:59:15 --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xfffffffffffffff7} ---
12:59:16 +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$
```

---

#### Valgrind output after using /usr/bin/env

```
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all /usr/bin/env LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/my_mem.so ls
==1640100== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1640100== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1640100== Using Valgrind-3.17.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1640100== Command: /usr/bin/env LD_PRELOAD=/home/ammarfaizi2/my_mem.so ls
==1640100== 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ammarfaizi2@integral:~$
```

Comment: Did you `strace` to make sure your `mmap` syscalls are actually returning pointers, not -ERRNO codes?  I forget if the length needs to be a multiple of the page size.  It looks like you are making sure they're aligned by at least 16 (`alignof(max_align_t)`), so if it's doing that correctly you malloc should satisfy the ABI.

Comment: Have you tried to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)? Why don't you use the real [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) function (actually [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)...)? You should compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and use [the Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Comment: To use GDB or other debuggers, you want to arrange for LD_PRELOAD to be set for the guest / target being debugged, but *not* GDB or strace itself.  One way is `strace -f  /usr/bin/env LD_PRELOAD=... ./a.out`, or GDB should let you set env vars for the guest.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have checked with `strace` with statically linked (that main function which is being commented in the code), and the `mmap` returned valid address and `munmap` returned 0.

I just tried to debug it with strace by executing via `/usr/bin/env` and got the above result (post has been edited).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I recompiled with `-Wall -Wextra -ggdb3`.

Comment: Have you debugged the core file? Please attach the call frames.

Comment: BTW, you can hopefully improve `realloc` to avoid copying by using `mmap` with a hint address (*without* MAP_FIXED) to map more pages after the current allocation if necessary.  The current malloc+memcpy should be considered a placeholder only, defeating any purpose of using mmap directly.  (Or just munmap any pages you can when shrinking.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have debugged the core file and fixed the crash, for the `free` function, you need to check if the argument is nullptr, for the `realloc` we need to hander `__user_ptr` is `nullptr` too.

```cpp
void free(void *__user_ptr) {
  if (!__user_ptr) return;
  // ...
}

void *realloc(void *__user_ptr, size_t new_len) {
  void *new_mem;
  size_t len;
  uint8_t diff;
  uintptr_t user_ptr = (uintptr_t)__user_ptr;

  new_mem = malloc(new_len);
  if (!__user_ptr) return new_mem;
  // ....
}
```

I have some experience in writing memory allocator libraries. During debugging, I find that some old c program uses `realloc` as `malloc` with a `nullptr` arguments, it's weird but is totally valid, please reference the man page

> The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to
> by ptr to size bytes. The contents will be unchanged in the range from
> the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new sizes. If
> the new size is larger than the old size, the added memory will not be
> initialized. If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to
> malloc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and
> ptr is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr). Unless ptr
> is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(),
> calloc() or realloc(). If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr)
> is done.

By the way, I see that you try to wrap the `syscall` for `mmap` and `munmap`, I suggest that we replace them with https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/linux-syscall-support , which is a production-level wrapper library and widely used. I think we should write as little code as possible to reduce potential errors.

Comment: The OP's wrapper for mmap *is* more efficient, so they are gaining some efficiency (smaller code size at least) by writing their own.  The linked library seems to be using stuff like `"movq %5,%%r10;"` for the last 3 args in x86-64 (in R10, R8, R9), instead of using GNU C `register ... asm("r10")` variables.  It also forces zero- or sign-extending all args to 64-bit, even when they're just `int`, although in this case the code is passing constants so the compiler can do that for free.

Comment: As usual for syscall wrapper libraries, they use a `"memory"` clobber on every syscall. For mmap I don't think you can safely omit the `"memory"` clobber to let the compiler avoid spill/reload of unrelated objects, but for syscalls like `write` (which only read memory), you can do better by telling the compiler about that fact for just that buffer ([How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259)).

Comment: Maybe for munmap, you could tell the compiler the pointed-to memory is an input for the asm statement, so all stores to it would have to be done ahead of the asm statement, not delayed until after (when they would fault).  Or tell the compiler it's a `"+m"` read/write operand, to make sure it doesn't try to delay a load until after it's unmapped.  Anyway, I guess this is really an argument to improve that header library, not to for everyone to roll their own.  Those optimizations to the wrappers aren't specific to this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

> gcc -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3 -shared mem.c -O3 -o my_mem.so

is wrong, if you want to build a shared library. See [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

You practically need a [position-independent-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) file, so use

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -ggdb3 -fPIC -shared mem.c -O3 -o my_mem.so
```

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.ukuug.org/events/linux2002/papers/pdf/dsohowto.pdf) and the [Program Library HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and [Linux Assembler Howto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/).

BTW, your `my_mmap` is naive, and don't handle failure cases of [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). See [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

You may want to study (for inspiration) the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or of [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/). Both have a better `mmap` implementation than yours.

You should consider using the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (or use [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/)), and use the [GCC address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer). Take more time to read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

PS. In 2021 see also the [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) project.

Comment: This `mmap` inline-asm looks totally fine to me, letting the compiler know about every register that's an unmodified input.  What's better about glibc's or musl's?  Are you talking about errno handling for mmap itself, which for Linux would mean checking for a `-errno` return value in the -4095 .. -1 range?

Comment: `musl` has a very readable implementation of  `mmap`. I don't understand the downvote: `-fPIC` was missing in OP question

Comment: Ok, that's nice, but what's wrong with this one?  I understand GNU C inline asm, and x86-64 Linux's syscall ABI, and this looks correct to me.

Comment: (Wasn't my downvote; `-fPIC` is a useful suggestion, although I'm pretty sure *not* the problem.  You don't want symbol-interposition for any of the internal calls in this library, and it doesn't use any static storage.  So the default `-fPIE` would happen to make good asm here.  Even `-fno-pie` would probably be the same.  Although you do have a bad habit of writing quite generic answers that tell people to write their own gcc plugin and link a bunch of docs, often without identifying the specific problem in the question. That's not entirely the case here, `-fPIC` is a good point; upvoted)

Comment: @PeterCordes talking about `-errno`, I blindly masked it with `0xffffffffffffff00ull`. I saw the possible values from my command line `errno --list`, and I think that mask is capable to handle all possible `-errno` values. Where is `-4095 .. -1` mentioned?

Comment: @AmmarFaizi: [AOSP non-obvious syscall() implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47566663) explains where the kernel itself reserves that range of values as error-returns (including for internal use), e.g. `#define MAX_ERRNO 4095`.  Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996410/linux-kernel-system-call-returns-1-instead-of-1-256/18998521#18998521) shows glibc's generic `syscall(2)` wrapper function which checks for that range regardless of syscall.

Comment: @AmmarFaizi: For mmap specifically, clearing the low 8 bits seems like the last thing you'd want to do, although bits 8 through 11 will still be set for anything greater than -256, so you'll still detect any of the errno codes that Linux currently uses.  Easier would be checking for any non-zero bits in the low 12 (page offset) because valid mmap returns must be page-aligned.