# Understanding Linux x86_64 Syscall Implementation in NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, calling-convention

I'm using the linux kernel as the basis for my 'OS' (which is just a game). Obviously, I use system calls to interact with the kernel, e.g. input, sound, graphics, etc. As I don't have a linker on this system to use pre-defined wrapper in `<sys/syscall.h>`, I use this syscall wrapper for C in NASM asm:

```
global _syscall
_syscall:
  mov rax, rdi 
  mov rdi, rsi
  mov rsi, rdx
  mov rdx, rcx
  mov r10, r8
  mov r8, r9
  mov r9, [rsp + 8]
  syscall
  ret
```

I understand the registers used based on System V calling convention. However, I don't understand the last line `mov r9, [rsp + 8]`. I feel like it has something to do with return address, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 7th arg is passed on the stack in x86-64 System V.

This is taking the first C arg and putting it in RAX, then copying the next 6 C args to the 6 arg-passing registers of the kernel's system-call calling convention.  (Like functions, but with R10 instead of RCX).

---

**The only reason the craptastic glibc `syscall()` function exists** / is written that way is because there's no way to tell C compilers about a custom calling convention where an arg is also passed in RAX.  That wrapper makes it look just like any other C function with a prototype.

It's fine for messing around with new system calls, but as you noted it's inefficient.  If you wanted something better in C, use inline asm macros for your ISA, e.g. https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/linux-syscall-support/blob/master/linux_syscall_support.h.  Inline asm is hard, and historically some `syscall1` / `syscall2` (per number of args) macros have been missing things like a `"memory"` clobber to tell the compiler that pointed-to memory could also be an input or output.  That github project is safe and has code for various ISAs.  (Some missed optimizations, like could use a dummy input operand instead of a full "memory" clobber...  But that's irrelevant to asm)

---

**Of course, you can do *much* better if you're writing in asm:**

Just use the `syscall` instruction directly with args in the right registers (RDI, RSI, RDX, R10, R8, R9) instead of `call _syscall` with the function-calling convention.  That's strictly worse than just inlining the `syscall` instruction: With `syscall` you know that registers are unmodified except for RAX (return value) and RCX/R11 (syscall itself uses them to save RIP and RFLAGS before kernel code runs.)  And it would take just as much code to get args into registers for a function call as it would for `syscall`.

**If you do want a wrapper function at all** (e.g. to `cmp rax, -4095 / jae handle_syscall_error` afterwards and maybe set errno), use the same calling convention for it as the kernel expects, so the first instruction can be `syscall`, not all that stupid shuffling of args over by 1.

Functions in asm (that you only need to call from asm) [can use whatever calling convention is convenient](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/165020#165020).  It's a good idea to use a good standard one most of the time, but any "obviously special" function can certainly use a special convention.

Comment: According to x86_64 ABI, syscalls return -1 <--> -4095 if error. The source you linked seems to only check -4095. Also, I don't understand why they cast in this error checking, e.g. `if ((u64)res >= (u64)-4095) { .. }`

Comment: @RyanMcClue: Yeah, `MAX_ERRNO` is 4095, leaving room for future expansion of error codes.  (While meaning that only 1 page has to be reserved to make sure error codes are distinct from valid pointers).  The cast to u64 makes sure we get an *unsigned* compare.  Remember that `-1ULL` is `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (the highest u64), and all bit-patterns that represent signed numbers from `-1` .. `-4095` also represent unsigned numbers above-or-equal to `-4095ULL`.  (And that in C on a 2's complement machine, int64_t <-> uint64_t casts are just a reinterpret of the bit-pattern.)

Comment: Oh yes, I was thinking in terms of logical shift not arithmetic.

Comment: @RyanMcClue: There is no shifting here, just compare.  That C `if()` can compile to the same `cmp rax, -4095` / `jae` I wrote in my answer, same as glibc's generic `syscall()` wrapper function uses. See [What are the return values of system calls in Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38751614)